# I want to change the id of select under tagname td

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

This is my code:

```
<tr>
<td class="demo">
    <label>nemo#2 Gender</label>
    <select id="custG2" required="required">
        <option>....</option>
        <option>M</option>
        <option>F</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <label>nemo#2 Gender</label>
    <select id="custG2" required="required">
        <option>....</option>
        <option>M</option>
        <option>F</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

(the among above two is of the class in  right at the beginning)

I want to change the id of one of the 'select'(either one not both) tag with the help of either jQuery or Javascript. Any help is appreciated.

**EDITED:**
Even if I could change the id of  that would just Do the work.

Comment: Which one, first or second ?

Comment: It's required to show what you've tried when asking a question. Also, I'm a bit conflicted as to why you'd want to change an ID? There should only be one ID per element so that it is unique, so If you're going to change it dynamically, why not make it a class?

Comment: Actually this a part big code which I am currently working on in which I am copying table which contains only one row initially and as I add more rows multiple <td> are created with same id's. So, I want to change id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll('select[id="custG2"]')` will return all  elements that `id="custG2"`, so just change the `id` attribute of the elements in this `NodeList`.

```js
var menus = document.querySelectorAll('select[id="custG2"]');
menus[0].id = 'new_id_1';
menus[1].id = 'new_id_2';
menus[1].disabled = true;
console.log(menus[0]);
console.log(menus[1]);
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="demo">
                <label>nemo#2 Gender</label>
                <select id="custG2" required="required">
                    <option>....</option>
                    <option>M</option>
                    <option>F</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>nemo#2 Gender</label>
                <select id="custG2" required="required">
                    <option>....</option>
                    <option>M</option>
                    <option>F</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I can't understand why you give the two items same ID.

Comment: I have changed the code a little included <tr> tags. Can you help? Problem is same. Previous I forgot to include them sorry!

Comment: @PratikDani Okay, I edited the answer. (add <table>, <tbody> and <tr>)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FT65JPJOU1JV check out this code I dont know where is my code going wrong. Actually when I add another block(using button) in it and then select 'single' in the dropdown the cust#2 gender and cust# age cells are not disappearing. While, I do this for the first row elements the same thing it absolutely works i.e. the cust#2 gender and cust# age cells are disappearing. Please help If possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PratikDani There are many wrongs. You add an event listender `$('#custinfo.1').on('change', ...` before the element is added. (It doesn't exist.) And the class names of new cells are `custG2.1` and `custAG2.1` ("dot" `.` is **invalid** in `class` name, and is **discouraged** in `id`), but still use `.custG2` and `.custAG2` selectors. Try **jQuery event delegate** in my example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FT671VQVLRNS (or you can dynamically add event listender)

Comment: Oh!! Now I understood my mistake.Thanks for pointing it out. How silly mistakes I made. Anyways thanks a lot!

Comment: What if you want to disable those two instead of hiding them? Please respond ASAP.

Comment: @PratikDani If you want to disable them, use `YourDOMElement.disabled = true;` or with jQuery: `$('.custG2 select').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTL4M8I9NZIS have a look at this code. When I am firstly selecting 'single' both the buttons are disabled(cust#2 gender and age), but the problem is if I click on add block button after that the buttons are still disabled and the cust type is also resetted to the 3 dots rather than having single option selected. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

ussing Jquery this code should work for your propouse

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $(select:first).attr("id") = "Whatever";
});
```

using css selectors and attr function I think is the best way